# Calculate the number of rows where year equals date in MySQL - JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json

Am trying to come up with a JSON result showing

```
`[{"Year":"2014-07","Numb":4},{"Year":"2015-07","Numb":12},{"Year":"2016-07","Numb":56}]`
```

"Numb" equals the number of rows that the year appears.  So the example above would be 4 rows where 2014 appears, 12 rows where 2015 appears and 56 rows where 2016 appears.

From there, the data is being placed into a Morris Chart. EG Number of clients who joined in YYYY. (Months are just used for the X Axis on the Morris Chart).

Am currently working with

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM signup ORDER BY DateAdded ASC LIMIT 0, 24";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query);

$total_rows =  $result->num_rows; // Show ALL rows regardless of date. Used in Array below

$array = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    $date = $row['DateAdded'];
    $time=strtotime($date);
    $year=date("Y-m",$time);
    array_push($array,array('Year'=>$year,'Numb'=>$total_rows));

}

echo json_encode($array);
```

Currently works OK in the Morris Chart except of course the number of rows are all the same.

Seems a fairly complex query that is out of my league.

I have researched the use of COUNT, but cannot see how it handles multiple queries within one query...

Comment: Consider providing proper CREATE and INSERT statements AND a desired result

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of the LIMIT in the above

Comment: LIMIT was leftover from testing - you can ignore..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont have the mysql table so i can not test it... Please test it and tell me if it works for you...

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM signup ORDER BY DateAdded ASC LIMIT 0, 24";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query);

$total_rows =  $result->num_rows; // Show ALL rows regardless of date. Used in Array below

$array = array();

function in_array_r($needle, $haystack, $strict = false) {
    foreach ($haystack as $key=>$item) {
        if (($strict ? $item === $needle : $item == $needle) || (is_array($item) && in_array_r($needle, $item, $strict))) {
            return $key;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    $year    =  date("Y-m",strtotime($row['DateAdded']));
    $key = in_array_r($year, $array);
    if($key !== false):
         $array[$key]["Numb"] += 1;
    else:
        $array[] = array("Year"=>$year,"Numb"=>1);
    endif;
}

echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: Please debug this your own or provide an sql somewhere so i can test... use `echo` and `die` and `print_r` to test...

Comment: Thx Praveen, debugging now..  The DB is nothing special, I'm just using the one column, "DateAdded" which is a timestamp...

Comment: NO problem..glad it helped you... :) BTW why it was giving `[]` only... ?

Answer (score 0):

Was creating another Morris Bar Chart using a simple query to count how many were signed up to a particular Membership Level.

Used this query as an alternative to @Praveen's answer, to come up with (for testing) the below.

```
$array = array();
foreach($mysqli->query('SELECT DateAdded, COUNT(*)  
FROM signup
WHERE CLientStatus REGEXP "Active"
GROUP BY DateAdded') as $row) {  
$year = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($row['DateAdded']));
array_push($array,array('Year'=>$year, 'Numb'=>$row['COUNT(*)']);
} 

 echo json_encode($array);
```

While this is producing Y-m-d instead of the original Y-m, there doesn't seems to be much difference in the final result. (other than more succinct)

This alternative "solution" better/worse/secure?